# set enable usrfield on the screen EP101000

Tags: acumatica

I would like enable an usrfield on the screen EP101000.
I try this code, but it's not possible.

```
protected void EPCustomWeek_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  
  var row = (EPCustomWeek)e.Row;
  if (row==null) return;
  PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<EPCustomWeekExt.usrjrsouvres>(cache, row, true); // false pour rendre non disponible
  Base.CustomWeek.AllowUpdate = true;        
  Base.CustomWeek.Cache.AllowUpdate = true;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to enable a custom field in this grid when I added

`PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly(cache, row, false);`

to your event handler, however it made the entire row enabled.
It seems like you need to implement the entire Base RowSelected logic to avoid it.